# The right steps to enter a value in the arguments x and y in Adjusted Rand Index?

Tags: r, clustered-index, hierarchical-clustering

Im attempting to use the **Adjusted Rand Index** to compare clustering results. Here, I use Iris data set as an example. These are the code:

```
iris.data=subset(iris, select=-Species)
iris.eucdist <- dist(iris.data, method="euclidean")
iris.sqeucdist <- iris.eucdist^2
iris.hc <- hclust(iris.sqeucdist, "ward")
plot(iris.hc, main="Dendrogram of Ward's Method", label=iris$Species)
table(cutree(iris.hc, 3), iris$Species)

##        setosa versicolor virginica
##   1     50          0         0
##   2      0         49        15
##   3      0          1        35
```

Firstly, I compute the ARI(Hubert and Arabie, 1985) manually, by using value in the table above. The answer is 0.7311986. However, when I using R, I cannot get the same answer.

```
library(mclust)
U=c(50,0,0,50,0,49,1,50,0,15,35,50)
V=c(50,0,0,50,0,49,15,64,0,1,35,36)
adjustedRandIndex(U,V)
## [1] 0.6961326
```

Perhaps, the way I put in the value is wrong. Is there a way to implement this so that the answer from R is same with manual computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `?adjustedRandIndex` suggests (states)  `x` and `y` should be vectors of class labels or similar, not the results of the cross-tabulation

```
adjustedRandIndex(cutree(iris.hc, 3), iris$Species)
```

gives

```
## [1] 0.7311986
```

Comment: Im confuse. So, @mnel. what is the correlation between value in cutree(iris.hc, 3) and iris$Species?

Comment: What do you mean by correlation? Have a look at [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27929/how-to-measure-correlation-between-categorical-variable) and associated links.

Comment: I mean what is the value in cutree(iris.hc, 3) and in iris$Species that will be compared? @mnel

Comment: The results of `cutree(iris.hc,3)` are the groups (species) predicted by the dendogram `iris.hc`. You are comparing these to `iris$Species` - the column of species names in the data set just as you did when you created the cross tabulation using `table(cutree(iris.hc, 3), iris$Species)`. The `adjustedRandIndex` uses the same information that created the table, but instead of returning the table, it returns a single number.

Comment: Your explanation helped me. Thank you @ mnel. :)